# Can I customize @using Html.BeginForm() by giving it a class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I looked through the different ways I can use

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

but I am still very confused. What I would like to do is to supply this with a class name so I could set up my own parameters.

Also I would like to supply a class to these:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Login.UserName)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: what parameters do you want to add? some query string? you can use `@using(Html.BeginForm(object routeValues))` where routeValues could be a class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes:

`@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "myClass" })`

and

`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Login.UserName, "Validation message", new { @class = "myOtherClass" })`

You can also do:

`@Html.BeginForm(htmlAttributes: new { @class = "myClass" })`

Comment: Thanks very much. I see you specify "Index", "Home".  Is there a way that I can let it default to the same script as with using (Html.BeginForm())

Comment: @Html.BeginForm(htmlAttributes: new { @class = "myClass" }) does not seem to work. Error:The best overload for BeginForm does not have a parameter named htmlAttributes

Answer (score 1):

There are overloads that accept `htmlAttributes` parameter.
Use it like this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Login.UserName, "validation message", new { @class="custom-class" } )
```